# Не срабатывают события

Tags: jquery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    
    $('.page-link').click(function(){
        
        pag_js = pagin($(this).text());
        $('.wrapper-breadcrumbs').html(pag_js); 
        
        return false;
        
    });
    
});
```

При первом клике по навигации, пункты смещаются. При последующих кликах, происходит переход по ссылке которая в пункте навигации.

Как избежать перехода по ссылке?

Comment: `$(document).on('click', '.page-link', function() {`

Comment: @Igor может стоит читать дальше заголовка прежде чем комменты строчить?

Comment: @teran Что я могу ответить на такой вопрос? Нет, не стоит.

Answer (score 1):

Для избежания перехода по ссылке следует прописать это:

```
$('.link-class').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
}
```